# Javascript - how to calculate difference between two time inputs automatically with bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap-datetimepicker from:

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Mainly because I need, in my application, a widget to display time. The other datepicker widgets handled, mostly, only dates, and I need a standardized widget.

Thing is, when I had the other widget on, this piece of code worked well with the following Javascript except:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-10">
    <div class="well with-header">
        <div class="header">
            <label th:for="timepicker4" th:value="${hourIntervalStart}" th:text="#{scheduler.intervalStartTime}">Hour Interval Start: </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="input-group">                                                   
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                <input name="hourIntervalStart" th:value="${hourIntervalStart}" th:field="*{hourIntervalStart}" id="timepicker4" class="form-control tp_interval1"></input> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
    <div class="well with-header">
        <div class="header">
            <label th:for="interval1" th:value="${increment}" th:text="#{scheduler.increment}">Interval (minutes): </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input name="increment" type="text" th:field="*{increment}" id="interval1" class="form-control" ></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-10">
    <div class="well with-header">
        <div class="header">
            <label th:for="timepicker5" th:text="#{scheduler.intervalEndTime}">Hour Interval End:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input name="hourIntervalEnd" id="timepicker5" type="datetime" th:value="${hourIntervalEnd}" th:field="*{hourIntervalEnd}" class="form-control tp_interval1" ></input>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript section that used to work nicely upon the onClose event of the widget is:

```
$('#timepicker4').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'pt-br',
    format: 'HH:mm'
});

$('#timepicker5').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'pt-br',
    format: 'HH:mm'
});

$('.tp_interval1').change(function () {
    // get values
        var valuestart = $('#timepicker4').val();
            var valuestop = $('#timepicker5').val();

            var start = moment(valuestart, 'HH:mm');
            var stop = moment(valuestop, 'HH:mm');

            // create date format
            var valuestart = new Date("01/01/2016 " + start).getTime();
            var valuestop = new Date("01/01/2016 " + stop).getTime();

            var diff = timeStop - timeStart;

            var minutesDiff = new Date(diff) / 60000; 

            $("#interval1").val(minutesDiff);
        });
```

What I want is that the time difference in minutes is automatically shown in the "#interval1" input.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use `$("#datetimepicker4").on("dp.change", function (e){}`. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139794/jquery-click-funtion-executes-only-once/37140633#37140633

Comment: Thanks, buddy, but it didn't work as expected

Comment: Is the event firing properly ?

Comment: Wait, where should I use it? On the `$('#timepicker4').datetimepicker();` like `$("#timepicker4").on("dp.change", function (e){}`?

Comment: I meant listen to `dp.change` instead of listening to just `change`. Instead of `$('.tp_interval1').change(function (){});` you may use `$("#timepicker4").on("dp.change", function (e){}`. Also you can get the date value using `e.date`.

Comment: I really can't see what you mean, can you please post an example?

Comment: Wrote an answer with an example. Didn't see that you had already answered. Anyways..let it be.

Comment: Thanks, buddy! I accepted your answer as a thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `dp.change` instead of the `change` event. As per the [documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/) you may use the following other events as well.

1. dp.hide
2. dp.show
3. dp.change
4. dp.error
5. dp.update

I added the event handler for one datetimepicker and it seemed to work. For the interval to reflect correctly, you need to add the `dp.change` event handler for datetimepicker2 as well - so that the interval changes also when a new date is chosen in datetimepicker2.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class='col-sm-4'>
        <input type='text' id="interval" value=''/>
    </div>
<div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript part:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
   });
   $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
   });

   $('#datetimepicker1').on('dp.change', function (e) {
        //here you can use e.date to get the date selected in the current datepicker
        var ms = e.date.diff($('#datetimepicker2').data('DateTimePicker').date());
        var d = moment.duration(ms);
        var s = Math.floor(d.asHours());
        $('#interval').val(s);
   });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I got it right by doing this:

```
$(".tp_interval1").on("dp.change", function (e){
    // get values
    var valuestart = $('#timepicker4').val();
    var valuestop = $('#timepicker5').val();

    var start = moment(valuestart, 'HH:mm');
    var stop = moment(valuestop, 'HH:mm');

    var diff = moment(stop, "HH:mm") - moment(start, "HH:mm");

    $("#interval1").val(diff / 60000);
});
```